# This type has a constructor and must be initialized here - Kotlin

Tags: android, constructor, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I just get started experimenting Android app using [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/). I just wanted to inherit [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class like this:

```
class SomeApp : Application {

}
```

But the compiler raises the warning:

[image]

and suggestion changes it to:

```
class SomeApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```

I read about [primary and secondary constructors in the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html). So if super class has a primary constructor, then is it necessary to write here? like Application class has its own constructor

```
public Application() {
    super(null);
}
```

then it would be necessary to have primary constructor for derived? or  Can't I do something like Java way:

```
class SomeApp : Application {
   constructor SomeApp(){
      super();
    }
}
```

or this error suggests something else? Can anyone explain me in detail? I'm very new to the language and this looks weird to me.

Edit: In java I can do the following: `class SomeApp extends Application{ }`

It has implicit constructor, so I do not have to write: `class SomeApp extends Application{ public Application(){ super(); } }` But in kotlin do I have to define empty constructor like the following:
`class SomeApp:Application(){ }`
?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is not about primary/secondary constructors.

On JVM (and pretty much anywhere else) a constructor of the base class `Application` is called when you create an instance of `SomeApp`

In Java the syntax is like you said:

```
class SomeApp : Application {
    constructor SomeApp(){
      super();
    }
}
```

Here you **must** declare a `constructor`, and then you **must** call a constructor of the super class.

In Kotlin the concept is **exactly** the same, but the syntax is nicer:

```
class SomeApp() : Application() {
    ...
}
```

Here you declare a constructor `SomeApp()` without parameters, and say that it calls `Application()`, without parameters in that case. Here `Application()` has exact the same effect as `super()` in the java snippet.

And in some cases some brackets may be omitted:

```
class SomeApp : Application()
```

The text of the error says: `This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here`. That means that type `Application` is a class, not an interface. Interfaces don't have constructors, so the syntax for them does not include a constructor invocation (brackets): `class A : CharSequence {...}`. But `Application` is a class, so you invoke a constructor (any, if there are several), or "initialize it here".

Comment: What you mean? That 's all there is to it

Comment: @KrupalShah I edited the answer. Is it what you were asking about?

Comment: So to my understand, there is no implicit empty constructor. Am i right?

Comment: @KrupalShah There is an implicit empty constructor if nothing else is specified, but you have to invoke it explicitly

Comment: So if an implicit empty constructor exists, why do i need to explicitly say compiler? This looks too weird to me. If you can explain better than please help.

Comment: That's simple: not like constructor declaration, constructor **invocation** is an action, which may have side effects. And no side effects might be implicit, that's the philosophy behind Kotlin

Comment: Actually, I personally not that sure that implicit constructor was such a great idea. You are not the first to get confused, and maybe that's a sign.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for helping. One last question: in java I extend Application class, it works well

Comment: @KrupalShah You mean explicit? There is an [explicit public nullary constructor in the Application class.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#Application())

Comment: @voddan how would I initialize a private constructor

Answer (score 8):

You don't need

```
class SomeApp : Application() {
   constructor SomeApp(){
      super();
    }
}
```

because this is equivalent. And if the class has a primary constructor, the base type can (and must) be initialized right there, using the parameters of the primary constructor.

```
class SomeApp : Application() {
}
```

which is also equivalent in java to

```
class SomeApp extends Application {
     public SomeApp(){
       super();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i am talking about Kotlin. What you are talking about to?

Comment: I think you're getting his "overriding `onCreate`" confused with declaring a constructor

Comment: Then I have no idea what he is asking. The reason the auto complete is adding in the `override onCreate` is because it saw he had an error in his constructor and decided to over eagerly add in an onCreate override.

Comment: Correct, the onCreate is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Convert

```kotlin
class SomeApp : Application {

}
```

To

````kotlin
class SomeApp : Application() { // just add ```()``` 

}
````